# VB - Error when Running Search

Tags: vb.net

I've recently finished a VB application, with some of your help, which has been working fine up until now. It is installed on 5 client machines but all have suddenly stopped working as of today and I haven't changed anything.

The application is set to auto update to the latest version from the server where I store the published files but these have not changed.

The application takes a string entered into a text box, searches an Excel file on a network drive for that string, takes the data in the next column (which is the path to a folder) and stores that as a string then opens the folder path.

This is the error I get, can anyone shed any light?

Thanks,

Jamie

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container..ctor(Object Instance)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at WindowsApplication1.Form1.GoBut_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18063 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
WD Design App 4.0
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Duncanw/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/LP40ZRTD.B6E/7GHED904.9XR/wdde..tion_76dba37807f38e9e_0001.0000_58ddc474ca533ea7/WD%20Design%20App%204.0.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34251 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18021 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34245 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    Assembly Version: 15.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 15.0.4737.1003
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
----------------------------------------
office
    Assembly Version: 15.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 15.0.4737.1003
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/office/15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/office.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that Excel file on a network drive is not locked for
   access. Try to make file copy with another name and test it.
2. Seems like error appears inside GoBut_Click function. Comment
   out it's code lines starting from bottom to find line where error
   appears.

Comment: Very Bizarrely the problem has resolved itself on all client machines which leads me to believe there was some sort of access issue to the file on the shared drive. Thanks for all you help and if it turns out this wasn't the problem I will come back to  you all. Thanks.